# Excel calculates correctly, but shows wrong result

Tags: excel

Good day

I have a little problem.
I am now working on an excel and there appeared an problem i have never
seen personally or even heard of.

I put in 42 in the hour format and divide it with 5 in another cell.

It showed 8.24 hours, but i know it should be 8.4 hours.

Firstly i did not notice it, till the control of mine.

I have seen where i reference on this exactly cell with the 8.24 hours, it calculates
everything with 8.4 hours. I checked the results with the calculator multiple times, but
to no avail.

So for the short version:

I calculate 42/5 and it should show 8.4, but it shows 8.24. On later calculations where i refer on this calculation it calculates with 8.4 and not with 8.24 even if this is what it shows.

How can i correct that, did i do an error, or what happened.

Thank you

Kind regards

Kirohn

I tried to change the format and than it worked, but it needs to be in the format [h]:mm.

I even tried if it works with other numbers than 5 and it worked. Only the 5 fails.

Sorry, my main language is german not english. sorry for the bad english i will be using or already used

Here an picture:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Au4.png)

Comment: For me `=42/5` shows `8.4`. What is cell format?

Comment: @Harun24hr sorry for my bad english. It's like number, currency, time, date, text, standard, etc.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot?

Comment: just did. just a little picture of it

Comment: Due to cell formatting it is showing that result. Follow as Spencer mention in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing 8 hours 24 minutes, which is 8.4 hours. Multiply that cell by 24 and format as general to get the correct result.

Comment: I am really stupid, thank you. I never thought about it that way.